# Simple and easy to use tool for managing different versions of files

Tags: version-control

I want to manage different sets of file versions locally on a machine without using complex version control tools like TFS/Git/SVN...etc. here is my use case:

- I have a Windows virtual machine that contains many xml, xslt, xsl, txt...etc. files, the virtual machine gets updated with every release of my product.
- Often I need to analyze errors in this virtual machine, so I change many files and run the product and start analyzing, let us call these file changes FileChangeSet1.
- based on the results above I need to change other files and maybe some of the files in FileChangeSet1 and do another test.
- again based on the results, I need to change more files, eventually I end up with FileChangeSet1, FileChangeSet2...FileChangeSet(n)

I want to:

- be able to switch between these file change sets easily and quickly, e.g. have a GUI that shows my my tree of FileChangeSets then click one of them and all files of that change are used.
- create file change sets from other file change sets e.g. copy FileChangeSet1 in FileChangeSet2 and change only one file in set 2
- I don't want to configure and install a complex version/source control system like TFS/Git/SVN where I have to create a database of all my files first.

Making snapshots of the virtual machine is not an option because it is extremely slow.

Comment: Nothing complicated about version control systems, well not compared to wanting version control with no system....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org) is the right tool for me. With it I can solve my business case easily as follows:

1. Install mercurial on Windows, it integrates in the Windows file explorer.
2. Create a local version control mercurial database by right clicking my root folder.
3. Now I can open all my files under my root folder in different text editors e.g. notepad++ and modify these files.
4. When I want to save/remember a specific status I simply commit the files to mercurial by right clicking the root folder, I can provide a commit note.
5. Later I can change my files in a different way and test how my system reacts to them, again I can commit these files locally.
6. Over time I have a history of change sets in Mercurial, I can go back to any change set, branch it, merge it...etc.

I have a huge and complex system that contains thousands of files, my root folder is actually the C:\ drive, I can easily and quickly make out of c: a version control database using mercurial.
All with a simple and intuitive GUI, no command line learning needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would not have much advantage with version control tools even because they are made to version text files. For binary files, I think you would end up like managing several diffent copies of the binary files anyway (at least for older tools such as CVS and SVN).

If you are running in linux, you may want to use cmp/diff tools. Take a look on incremental diff and diff tools such as patchutils.

Consider also to create a checksum of huge files to avoid comparing them for nothing.

ps. also take a look on this - http://jojodiff.sourceforge.net/ - haven't tried but it seems simple to use and promising.